# How to print data as a table in python on a local host

Tags: python

```
for issues in response.json()["issues"]:
    p = (issues["fields"]["creator"]["emailAddress"])
    rep+=(p[:-8]+"\n")
print(rep)
```

This will give me email with duplicates

```
abc@company.com
abc@company.com
cde@company.com
cde@company.com
```

I want to print the string with their count available in a table using python,Please help me with this

```
abc@company.com 2
cde@company.com 2
```

Comment: I want to print this in a table and i don't know how to do it in python and i don't want to read character full email id

Comment: Please help me to how to create tables in python

Comment: This is not a duplicate question